# Iteration limit

Tags: python, optimization, iteration

How can fix the errors:"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars" and "AssertionError: Iteration limit reached". My code is for an optimization problem. I  thought perhaps the initial conditions have caused this error. I changed them but the error is still there. My code is following:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from scipy.special import roots_legendre, eval_legendre

from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint
# create variables
N=8;n1=2;n2=3;n3=2;n4=3;z=1;m=2;a=0;b=1
x = [sp.symbols('x%d' % i) for i in range(2*(n1+n2+n3+n4)-4)]
s=zeros(2*n1-1,1);e=zeros(2*n2-1,1);h=zeros(2*n3-1,1);l=zeros(2*n4-1)
for i in range(2*n1-1):
    s[i]=x[i]
for i in range(2*n2-1):
    e[i]=x[i+2*n1-1]
for i in range(2*n3-1):
    h[i]=x[i+2*(n1+n2)-2]
for i in range(2*n4-1):
    l[i]=x[i+2*(n1+n2+n3)-3]   
#s = [sp.symbols('s%d' % i) for i in range(2*n1-1)]
#e = [sp.symbols('e%d' % i) for i in range(2*n2-1)]#Instead of "i" we choose "e"
#h = [sp.symbols('h%d' % i) for i in range(2*n3-1)]
#l = [sp.symbols('l%d' % i) for i in range(2*n4-1)]
from sympy.abc import t
B=zeros(N,N)
number = range(N)
for i in number:
   for j in number:
       if i<j :
           B[i,j]=0
       else :
           B[i,j]=sp.factorial(i+j)/(2**j*sp.factorial(j)*sp.factorial(i-j))
PS=Matrix(1,n1,s[0:n1]);PI=Matrix(1,n2,e[0:n2]);PH=Matrix(1,n3,h[0:n3]);PL=Matrix(1,n4,l[0:n4])
TS=[[1]];TI=[[1]];TH=[[1]];TL=[[1]]
for i in range(n1-1):
    TS.append([t**(s[n1+i]+i+1)])
for i in range(n2-1):    
    TI.append([t**(e[n2+i]+i+1)])
for i in range(n3-1):        
    TH.append([t**(h[n3+i]+i+1)])
for i in range(n4-1):            
    TL.append([t**(l[n4+i]+i+1)])
MTS=Matrix(TS);MTI=Matrix(TI);MTH=Matrix(TH);MTL=Matrix(TL)
BS=B[0:n1,0:n1];BI=B[0:n2,0:n2];BH=B[0:n3,0:n3];BL=B[0:n4,0:n4]
S=PS*BS*MTS;II=PI*BI*MTI;H=PH*BH*MTH;L=PL*BL*MTL

#CONVERT SYMPY MATRICES TO NUMPY ONE
S0=np.array(S);I0=np.array(II);H0=np.array(H);L0=np.array(L)
GS=zeros(n1,n1);GI=zeros(n2,n2);GH=zeros(n3,n3);GL=zeros(n4,n4)

for i in range(n1):
   if i==0:
      GS[i,i]=0
   else:
       GS[i,i]=simplify(gamma(s[n1+i-1]+1)/gamma(s[n1+i-1]+1-z))
for i in range(n2):
    if i==0:
      GI[i,i]=0
    else:
     GI[i,i]=simplify(gamma(e[n2+i-1]+1)/gamma(e[n2+i-1]+1-z))
for i in range(n3):
    if i==0:
      GH[i,i]=0
    else:
      GH[i,i]=simplify(gamma(h[n3+i-1]+1)/gamma(h[n3+i-1]+1-z))
for i in range(n4):
    if i==0:
      GL[i,i]=0
    else:
      GL[i,i]=simplify(gamma(l[n4+i-1]+1)/gamma(l[n4+i-1]+1-z))     
DS=simplify(t**(-z)*PS*BS*GS*MTS)
DI=simplify(t**(-z)*PI*BI*GI*MTI)
DH=simplify(t**(-z)*PH*BH*GH*MTH)
DL=simplify(t**(-z)*PL*BL*GL*MTL)
RS=DS[0,0]-(.0043217-.5944*S[0,0]*II[0,0]-(.025+3.5)*S[0,0])
RI=DI[0,0]-(.5944*S[0,0]*II[0,0]+.0056*H[0,0]*II[0,0]+.27*L[0,0]-(.025+3.5+.0025+.5)*II[0,0])
RH=DH[0,0]-(.535-.0056*H[0,0]*II[0,0]+.5*II[0,0]-(.025+3.5)*H[0,0])
RL=DL[0,0]-(.0025*II[0,0]-(.025+3.5+.27)*L[0,0])      
#f = lambdify(t, R)
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec=4
def R(k):
   return (RS**2+RI**2+RH**2+RL**2).subs(t,k)
r, w = roots_legendre(m)
F=zeros(1,m)
I1=0
for i in range (m):
   F[i]=r[i]*R((b-a)/2*r[i]+(b+a)/2)
   I1=I1+F[i]
OF1=((b-a)/2)*I1 #OF=Objective Function
OF=OF1.evalf(3)
t = next(s for s in S.free_symbols if s.name == 't')
x = [
    next(s for s in OF.free_symbols if s.name == f'x{i}')
    for i in range(2*(n1+n2+n3+n4)-4)
]
args = [t, *x]
OF = sp.lambdify(args, OF)
S = sp.lambdify(args, S.flat()[0])
I = sp.lambdify(args, II.flat()[0])
H = sp.lambdify(args, H.flat()[0])
L = sp.lambdify(args, L.flat()[0])

def objective(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return OF(*params)

def Sc(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return S(*params)
def Ic(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return I(*params)
def Hc(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return H(*params)
def Lc(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return L(*params)

res = minimize(
    fun=objective,
    x0=np.ones(1 + 2*(n1+n2+n3+n4)-4),
    constraints=(
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Sc, lb=43994, ub=43994),
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Ic, lb=1, ub=1),
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Hc, lb=1, ub=1),
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Lc, lb=1, ub=1),
    ),
)
assert res.success, res.message
print(res)
```

Comment: You're missing bounds; add those. Also add all five Jacobians.

Comment: Read https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixCalculus.jacobian

Comment: Which bounds and five Jacobians do you mean?

Comment: All of them. Bounds on every variable. Also, Jacobian for the objective and all four constraints.

Comment: Alright. Thankyou

Comment: I have no bound for variables .Because i applied  the minimize command, Is it necessary to calculate jacobian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of iterations can be changed in the `minimize` function. This can be combined with the `tol` parameter that sets the tolerance for the convergence. For example,

```
res = minimize(                                                                                         
    fun=objective,                                                                                      
    x0=np.ones(1 + 2*(n1+n2+n3+n4)-4),                                                                  
    constraints=(                                                                                       
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Sc, lb=43994, ub=43994),                                                
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Ic, lb=1, ub=1),                                                        
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Hc, lb=1, ub=1),                                                        
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Lc, lb=1, ub=1),                                                        
    ),                                                                                                  
    tol=1.e-3,                                                                                          
    options={"maxiter": 2000}                                                                           
)
```

That said, the warnings you get before hitting the error seem to be related to why your problem is failing to converge.

You should check whether the function you're trying to optimize is correct, and if it is, then you should explore its mathematical properties in order to pick the right optimization method. `minimize` offers several methods, see the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after adding the commands `tol=1.e-3,                                                                                          
    options={"maxiter": 2000}`  the error still there.

Comment: I never claimed those values would work, I just gave them as examples of the features you were ignoring. The rest of my answer says you should study your problem in a more thorough way before hoping for default parameters to magically work for your (apparently very convoluted) problem.

Comment: I tested all of methods that you introduce in the link but the error still exists.